# Do any NAS devices support full disk encryption using a TPM and SEDs?

Tags: nas

I'm looking to buy an 8+ bay, rackmount NAS device.  One of the features I'd like is full drive encryption using self encrypting drives (SEDs) and a trusted platform module (TPM).  Does anyone make such a thing?  Synology does not.  It's looking like Seagate does not either (which is weird, since they manufacture SEDs).

Comment: Do the drives need to be hot swappable?

Comment: Yes.  And they will be part of a RAID 1 volume.  Probably use Seagate Enterprise 4TB, SED Markara.

Comment: The 3.5" SATA drives, or something else? Do you already have another computer, or would a new platform work? What's your budget? Do you particularly care about power?

Comment: The large capacity, enterprise quality, drives that Seagate makes that I would use are all 3.5" drives.  I am either buying or building a NAS device to add to my existing equipment.  I prefer buying, as I am under the delusion that I will get better support that way.  I'd spend around $2K for a NAS.  I'm not too concerned about power.

Comment: Would you be willing to buy used hardware?

Comment: Do you want to be able to set an authentication key at a hardware level, or is software fine?

Comment: I was hoping to use the TPM to generate and store a key. Perhaps I would be forced to enter a password of sorts at boot time (booting the NAS I mean) and may need to write some recovery key to a flash drive that I keep safe somewhere.  I want no data to be readable in the event a thief steels the entire NAS or just one of its drives.

Comment: Do you want support for TPM 2.0, or is 1.2 okay?